# Test a form in React with jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm totally lost trying to test a simple form made with React, how do I know if the submit button is working? After some research I thought that the way to do it is to make a mock function and then check if it was called but I'm pretty sure I'm doing it completely wrong.

```
onObjSubmit(event){
event.preventDefault()
..... (fetch something)
}

render(){
  return (
    <form id="myForm" onSubmit={event => this.onObjSubmit(event)}>
     <input type="text" id="name" /><br />
     <input type="text" id="last_name" /><br />
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  );
}
```

And the test:

```
it('Test', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestComp />);
  const fn = jest.fn();
  wrapper.instance().onObjSubmit = fn;
  wrapper.update();
  wrapper.find('#myForm').simulate('submit');
  expect(fn).toBeCalled();
});
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the only one who feels lost with this one. [This thread on Enzyme's issues page](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/308) has a lot of suggested approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: Links to vague external resources are not considered valuable to the community. Please post the relevant information here, in your question.